# Special Timer Switch, Turn off every X days for 1 minute

Tags: switches

Please help me out finding a timer switch that is capable of turning off, or disrupting the current once per day or in X days for a minute or so.

More concretely here is my problem: I have a Linux router that completely freezes sometimes. I need to restart it by plunging in and out. Can not log in. Sometimes I am not home for a couple of days. In such cases it would be good to have a timer that would restart it by turning it off and restarting it. I do not want a heartbeat. If I lose a half of day that is fine. What I would like that the next day my router is up and running.

I do not want to build one. In the original question I asked for a commercial product but, the smartasses of the stackexchanges voted my question out. So I am rephrasing it: Please name search keywords with what I can find a "buyable" solution.

Comment: Some routers are prone to DoS stack overflow, some are caused by surfing habits of users , while others from insufficient RAM  in router. If you can analyze , a better solution may exist but it is possible use Windows and AT cmdlines to create a timer to send commands to reset router from LAN. Otherwise brute force relay momentary toggles may be generated to AC driving router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the router on a [programmable switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MVF16JG). Maybe have it do a restart in the middle of the night.

Comment: This is a good answer. Includes concrete and commercial agnostic answer too, by naming programmable switch. However I was aware of these switches, but the ones I found were unable to do this. The ones I saw were able to turn on after X time or be turned off Y time. A more precise keyword would be: "7 Day Digital Programmable Timer". I accept and thank you for the answer. :-)